# New Firebase - Cannot query data. What is the new syntax?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to move to the new Firebase from the old one (launched today, May 18th, 2016), but the query syntax is unclear to me.  The only example I can find to make a query is via a listener.

I've followed the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data), but they are very unclear as to how to simply query one piece of data in the Firebase realtime DB.

The old docs were fine, but the new ones are terrible, imo.  Also, their examples on github, where I got some of the code I'm now trying to use, are overly complex (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/database/DatabaseExampleSwift).

The code runs fine, I have a new project set up in the Firebase admin console online, I have the new plist file set up and in xcode, and everything compiles fine.  I just need code to easily access one measly piece of data!  Plz help.

Thanks.

Here's my code (runs fine / is configured fine), but can't display the data:

```
class LatestNewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // get the Feed URL from Firebase:
    lazy var FireBaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var FeedURLRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
```

---

Then, in viewDidLoad(), I'm doing this:

```
FeedURLRef = FireBaseRef.child("AppGlobals").child("FeedURL")

refHandle = FireBaseRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    let FirebaseFeedURL = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
    print("FirebaseFeedURL = " + String(FirebaseFeedURL))
})
```

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, can you please be more clear?

Comment: More clear?  I'm not able to display the content from the DB that I'm obtaining with the above code.  Specifically, the "print()" statement I'm using to debug this and display the content isn't running.

Comment: So it's not even printing out the "FirebaseFeedURL"?

Comment: Correct, it is not even printing out the "FirebaseFeedURL".

Comment: What if you print out the snapshot? Also I'd recommend following swift conventions when naming your variables. It's a bit hard to read.

Comment: Nothing gets printed out at all, though.  Not even if I were to print out "Hello World!".  As for convention I quickly changed variable name for posting here on Stack Overflow...  That's the least of my concerns right now.